# SSRS Finishes but does not return to the caller

Tags: c#, reporting-services, timeout, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

We have ssrs service with executiontimeout set as 2.5 hr. We also have timeout setting set to 12 hr before calling the ReportExecutionService render() method.

The problem is that everytime any ssrs run for more than 1 hr, fails to return the call to the caller.

SSRS exeuction log shows that report finished successfully however it never returns the result to caller. Caller times out after waiting for 12 hr. All the reports under 1 hr executes fine and returns the call.

Can anyone suggest where to look for issues ?

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout = "9000" /> //2.5hr
</system.web>
```

C# caller to SSRS webservice

```
    // Initialize Reporting Service
    ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService()
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AppSettings.SSRS_Server_UserName, AppSettings.SSRS_Server_Password),
        Url = string.Format("http://{0}/{1}/{2}", AppSettings.SSRS_Server_Name, AppSettings.SSRS_Server_Path,AppSettings.SSRS_Service_ExecutionURL),
        ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader(),
        Timeout = AppSettings.SSRS_WebTimeOut, //12 hr in Milliseconds //Timeout.Infinite,
    };
```

Z

Answer (score 0):

We found out we had firewall rule which would drop the http connection after 1 hr. This is horrible because we dont get reply back from ssrs and client is left hanging without any response.